# Console log not working

Tags: javascript, logging, google-chrome-extension, console

I am new to Javascript and am trying to make a Chrome extension. However, the console log isn't printing anything to the console I opened using f12. The code executes other functions, like opening a tab, but prints nothing. I've searched through a lot of questions about the same problem but none of the causes seemed to be mine. Thanks.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener (function (tab)
{
    var teste = new Object();
    chrome.tabs.create  (teste);
    alert(123);
    chrome.tabs.executeScript( {file:"viewer.js"});
});
```

Comment: And if you replace console.log with alert(123), does it come up?

Comment: where is you code..? also check `if (window.console) { }`

Comment: If I use alert(123), it comes up. Also, added the code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the extion list page, you should be able to inspect background page. (There will be a link there)

Answer (score 0):

If you're app is running from the pop-up, you have direct access to the background page via the [chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage) method.

Therefore, you can log to the console like this:

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log('hello');
```

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious, but did you inspect the proper console? Specifically, right click on the extension icon --> inspect pop up?

Comment: I am not using a pop up (it's an event page), so I can't use inspect pop up. I'm using the f12 console.

Comment: Perhaps consider Message Parsing? (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998775/chrome-extension-message-passing/2999305?noredirect=1#2999305

Comment: But it is on the background script that I can't write on console

Comment: @Hrodruck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970648/about-debugging-chrome-extension

Comment: I can see the background logs, but not the content script ones. I'ts not a fault in my program since I downloaded a sample program and still couldn't see the content script logs